# How to make a dynamic meta descripition in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I make the **description** , which is in an `Array` in the `controller` , to be rendered to the `<meta name="description" content="{{metadescription}}">` , which is on index.html , and can dynamically appear in **views** ?

I use `$routeParams`; when I put: `title: ':pageName'` the title is replaced by the current route, to access the page. I need to do something similar in `metadescription` , making the **description** that is within the Array `items` in the controller `NatureCtrl` **appear in views**.

Controller

```
angular.module('tareasApp')
  .controller('NatureCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $sce, $location, $anchorScroll) { 

    $scope.pageName = $routeParams.pageName;

$scope.items =[
 {    
      href:'/relaxing-sounds-waves', 
      img:'waves.jpg', 
      description:'Those Relaxing Sounds of Waves'
 },
 {    
      href:'/relaxing-ocean-sounds', 
      img:'ocean.jpg', 
      description:'Nature Sounds Relaxing Ocean Sounds'
 }
];
 });
```

app.js

```
     var myApp = angular.module('tareasApp')
          myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
              .when('/:pageName', {
                        templateUrl: 'views/wizard.html',
                        title: ':pageName',
                        metadescription: '',
                        controller: 'NatureCtrl'
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                      redirectTo: '/'
                    });
                });

    // That way I can get page titles based on the route and routeParams.
   //How do I set the $rootScope.metadescription for a description concerning each page?

    myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
       $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current) {
       var title = current.$$route.title;
    if (title && $routeParams){
        for(var PageName in $routeParams) {
            title = title.replace(new RegExp(':' + PageName, 'g'), $routeParams[PageName]);
        }
    }
    $rootScope.title = title;
    $rootScope.metadescription = current.$$route.metadescription;
         });
     }]);
```

Page index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" ng-app="tareasApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
<meta name="description" content="{{metadescription}}">
<base href="/">
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
</head>

<body>
   Content goes here... the views are injected here...
</body>
</html>
```

### **Edited:**

The key point is: How do I configure `myApp.run` for the `metadescription` can work similar to the title?

```
myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current) {
           var metadescription = current.$$route.metadescription;
        if (metadescription && <!-- What I put here?-->){
            for(var PageDesc in <!-- What I put here?-->) {
                metadescription = metadescription.replace(new RegExp(':' + PageDesc, 'g'), <!-- What I put here?-->[PageDesc]);
            }
        }
        $rootScope.metadescription = metadescription;
             });
         }]);
```

Comment: Could you try `ng-attr-content="{{metadescription}}"` instead of just `content`?

Comment: The point is that I use $ routeParams , and need to dynamically insert the description .

Comment: Can stick a controller or directive on the head and listen for routeChange events in that controller/directive. Then just change the variables accordingly

Comment: You could post an example? That way would be indexed in google search engine? The title is crawler, just missing the description .

Comment: Actually I didn't really look at the routeChange code you already have..seems to me it should already be working if title is. What's it doing?

Comment: I left the title for an example ... I want to do similarly in the description. I'm not knowing how to set up 'myApp.run' in order to work.